# Can you have a graph/plot with more than 3 sides?

Tags: graphing-functions, visualization

It may be a stupid question but I was working on a ternary plot (example image attached) and the idea about the maximum number of sides for a graph (in 2D, 3D and ND) came up. I'm curious as to the reason why/why not a graph/plot with more sides would/wouldn't be feasible, and any deeper maths behind this[image]

Comment: this is just what happens if you take the plane $x+y+z = 1$   in 3-space,  with $x,y,z \geq 0.$  Switch each percentage to a decimal, $30\%  \mapsto 0.30 $

Comment: Perhaps a hexagonal graph, similar to this one, would work

Comment: I made a tag called graph-paper; your question has nothing to do with planar-graphs. I wish more students would learn by drawing graphs by hand, at least the common $y= f(x)$  type on square-printed paper

Comment: The diagram you show, if the scales are independent, is an isometric view of a 3d space with its known drawbacks.

Comment: @WillJagy Please do not invent new tags without first running it by the community. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35451/

Comment: The scales are not independent, they are mole fractions and must obey $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 =1$